# Conditional Expectation on Information Subsets

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose, it is time $t$, and you have a time based random variable $x_{t+2}$ and two events $A_{t+1},A_{t+2}$ that relate to the random variable $x$ which updates every period. The events relate to whether it crosses a non-negativity threshold $A_{t+2}=\{x_{t+2} \geq 0 \}$ and $A_{t+1}=\{x_{t+1} \geq 0 \}$

Here is the twist, event $A_{t+2}$ cannot happen if $A_{t+1}$ does not occur.  Hence the fact $A_{t+2}$ is a possibility implies $A_{t+1}$ occurred. Moreover $A_{t+2}$ contains all the information $A_{t+1} $ has, in other words, $A_{t+1} \subset A_{t+2}$ .

My Goal: I want to take the conditional expectation below

$$E_t[x_{t+2}|A_{t+2},A_{t+1}]$$

In order to do it, can I make the following simplifying assumption?

$$E_t[x_{t+2}|A_{t+2},A_{t+1}]=E_t[x_{t+2}|A_{t+2}]$$

Is this correct? Thank you!

(This is a survival model)

Answer (score 1):

Your setup seems inconsistent. From what you write about $A_{t+1}$ and $A_{t+2}$, we have $A_{t+2}\subseteq A_{t+1}$, not the other way around.

If that's what you meant, then indeed

$$E_t[x_{t+2}\mid A_{t+2},A_{t+1}]=E_t[x_{t+2}\mid A_{t+2}\cap A_{t+1}]=E_t[x_{t+2}\mid A_{t+2}]\;.$$

Comment: Hi thanks for responding but I am not sure why you claim $A_{t+2}\subseteq A_{t+1}$

Comment: If we were to assume two time periods $t=2$ and the event $A$ represent "Live" and $A'$ is the event you "Die". The outcome of the event $A_{t+2}$ tells you if you survived/died the last period. The outcome of the event carries all prior history leading up to it. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. You already wrote that in the question, and I didn't disagree with it. The only thing I disagreed with was that you wrote $A_{t+1}\subseteq A_{t+2}$ and it should be $A_{t+2}\subseteq A_{t+1}$, precisely because you're right that $A_{t+2}$ contains all the information that $A_{t+1}$ contains. The larger the event, the less information it contains. $A_{t+2}$ implies $A_{t+1}$ and not the other way around.